# Why are Vox Repeater upgrades unavailable?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

The only Vox weapon upgrades available at the Minuteman's Armory is for the Burstgun. I am unable to upgrade the Vox Repeater. (Playing on PC and just got the Undertow vigor.) Is this a glitch, or...?

Comment: Well, the good news are: The Vox Repeater *does* have upgrades, and there is still one more Vigor after Undertow, meaning there's still time for Repeater upgrades to appear.

Comment: You are so correct.  A few minutes later, I found the recoil reducer just before the Prosperity Plaza skirmish. Impatient.

Comment: @Nolonar, it sounds like your comment solved OPs problem, perhaps you should list it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The gun upgrades are only available at certain chapters. The game does not give you the option for all of the upgrades at once.

Once you progress further into the story, the upgrades will be available.